# Excel - VBA - Create Combination of unique codes of each primary key

Tags: excel, vba

I need to create a combination of unique codes separated by a comma.

#### What I really need

I Would like that stack community helps me to make a **FASTER** and **more efficient** process... Maybe using only VBA...

#### Sample Data base

| AB | AC | COMBINATION |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 41771067424895000677550010000477911436409011 | 2556 | 2556 |
| 77161087658787000161550010000677811133532252 | 2556 | 2407, 2556 |
| 77161087658787000161550010000677811133532252 | 2407 | 2407, 2556 |

- `AB` unique keys from database;
- `AC` is a code, where the unique key could have one or more;
- `AD` What i want to display;

#### Formula

For this, I have made a formula that works...

```
=TEXTJOIN(", "; TRUE; (UNIQUE(FILTER(AC:AC;AB:AB=AB7))))
```

#### My macro

```vb
sub myMacro()

    Sheets("ANEXO 7").Range("AD6").Value = "LISTA CFOP ÚNICOS POR NF"
    Range("AD7").Formula2 = "=TEXTJOIN("", "", TRUE, (UNIQUE(FILTER(AC:AC,AB:AB=AB7))))"
    
    Sheets("ANEXO 7").Range("AD7").Copy
    ultima_linha = Sheets("ANEXO 7").Range("AB6").End(xlDown).Row
    Sheets("ANEXO 7").Range("AD7" & ultima_linha).Select
    Sheets("ANEXO 7").Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

### The Problem

This whole process...

- Uses 100% of CPU;
- Takes too much time (5 min)

[image]

Comment: So you are saying that COMBINATION represents all AC values with matching AB values? Do you have control of the SQL that hits the DB to get this data? You would likely get the best performance by asking the DB to organize the result set differently in the SQL statement. Generally, excel formulas are going to be very bad at this kind of operation. If you don't have control of the SQL, the next best thing is to process in memory via VBA

Comment: Hi... This is one of many things that we had done on this DATA.  We have data from multiple sources.  I am tryng to have more efficient with this analysis.

Comment: The 1st thing that comes to mind (if you want to go this route using a formula) that will save ton's of time is to remove whole column references. Especially with these heavy array-type formulas it almost never is a good idea to run those on whole columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FillDown method should be considerably faster than a copy/paste.  Try this code and let us know.

```
Sub myMacro()
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Sheets("ANEXO 7").Range("AD6").Value = "LISTA CFOP ÚNICOS POR NF"
    Range("AD7").Formula2 = "=TEXTJOIN("", "", TRUE, (UNIQUE(FILTER(AC:AC,AB:AB=AB7))))"

    ultima_linha = Sheets("ANEXO 7").Range("AB6").End(xlDown).Row
    Sheets("ANEXO 7").Range("AD7:AD" & ultima_linha).FillDown
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: I am waiting the last processs that is on the backgroung...As soon as it finishes I will try and give you the feedback!   Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @AndreNevares I wanted to add to this, you could benefit further by turning calculations to manual before filling the formulas, then turn calculations back to automatic (if that's what they are usually set to)